# swig, python: can not imported generated module

Tags: python, swig

I have generated a python module that wrapping up some c++ code. The code is  a toy:

```
// example.h
#ifndef example_header_h
#define example_header_h

class try_class
{
public:
    try_class();
    void class_func(int a);
};

#endif

// example.cpp

#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>
try_class::try_class()
{
    std::cout << "try class" << std::endl;
}

void try_class::class_func(int a)
{
   
}

// example.i
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

The compiling is ok. Then, I collect `example.py`, `_example.pyd` in a folder. In this folder, I open a python interpreter.

When I import `example`, a bug is reported:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_GET: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: unknown
```

My environment is:

```
vs 2022
CMake 3.22.1
swig 4.0.2
python 3.10.5
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Posting an error message only is not an answerable question

Comment: I am sorry for this mistake. I have supplied more information in the post.

Comment: The code provided works fine in my build environment so the problem is with the build process.  You'll have to provide more instruction to reproduce your problem.