# swig cannot wrap exported c++ file into python

Tags: python, swig

I am using `swig` to wrap c++ into python.

My `PackA.h` is:

```
#ifndef PACKA_HEADER_H
#define PACKA_HEADER_H

#include <string>
class  PackA
{
public:
    PackA();

};

#endif
```

And my `PackA.i` is:

```
%module PackA

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "PackA.h"
%}
%include "PackA.h"
```

It successfully generate python module.

However, if I declare `PackA` to dll by:

```
// #include "PackAGlobal.h"

#ifndef PACKA_EXPORTES_H
#define PACKA_EXPORTES_H

#if (WIN32)
    #ifdef PackA_EXPORTS
        #define PackA_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define PackA_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define PackA_EXPORT
#endif


#endif

// PackA.h
#ifndef PACKA_HEADER_H
#define PACKA_HEADER_H

#include "PackAGlobal.h"
#include <string>
class  PackA
{
public:
    PackA();

};

#endif
```

VS reports bugs:

```
c4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. note c++ does not support default-int
c2071 abstract declarator illegal storage class
c2513: PackA:  no variable declared before =
```

How can I wrap this export class into python?

Update-----------------------------------------------------------

Thank suggestion from @Mark Tolonen.

I modify my `PackA.i` as:

```
%module PackA

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "PackA.h"
%}
%include <windows.i>
%include "PackA.h"
```

However, the bug is still remained.

I have uploaded the example code to github: https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/SwigTest

Comment: There is no `=` in the source provided.  What is `PackAGlobal.h`?  Provide a [mcve] and exact instructions to reproduce the error.

Comment: Also if you use `__declspec` you need to `%include <windows.i>` in the SWIG interface.

Comment: Sorry for not declaring `PackAGlobal.h`, and I have supplied the information. In addition, I have included `%include <windows.i>` in my `PackA.i`, but the bug is remained with no change.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  The definition for `PackA::PackA()` is missing.  Is there a `PackA.cpp`?  If I add a trivial implementation it compiles fine.  Make sure to include all files to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, there is a `PackA.cpp`. I have a complete c++ project, and want to wrap it to python. That's the reason why I declare `PackA` to export library, because it would be imported by `PackB`. The complete c++ project contains several files, and I have uploaded they to [github](https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/SwigTest). Could you please have a check for it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Like your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72921720/235698) this code builds fine for me.  I'm not using CMake and am no expert in it, but it is a build issue, not a coding issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply. I will check the building processing one more time.

Comment: Finally, I know what's the problem with my code. 1. I need to `%include "PackAGlobal.h"` in `PackA.i`; 2. I need to `set_target_properties(PackAWrapping properties compile_definitions PackA_EXPORTS)`.

Comment: Ah I linked to the .cpp file directly and the class didn’t need exporting. You were building as a DLL.  Remember to include all steps to reproduce issues in the question in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution, and I have uploaded the correct code to github: https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/SwigTest. Hope it can help someone.

The solution is:

1. add `%include "PackAGlobal.h"` in `PackA.i`.
2. declare `PackA_EXPORTS` for `PackAWrapping`:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(PackAWrapping
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS PackA_EXPORTS
)
```